# "namespace std {}" before "using namespace std;"

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have seen the syntax below in many places where STL classes are used without explicitly qualifying them with `std::`.  What is the advantage of the initial `namespace std {}`?  Why not just put `using namespace std;`?

```
namespace std {}
using namespace std;
```

Comment: @Steephen: What? How? The OP's question is not addressed at all in that "duplicate", as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are right, I didn't read question clearly. Reverted my closing vote.

Answer (score 10):

`namespace std {}` simply *declares* the namespace so that the compiler knows about it and doing `using namespace std;` won't cause an error.

Later in the code stuff from `std::` can be `#include`d and they can be automatically referred to without the `std::` prefix.

Comment: That would mean the includes come after the using directive, which is a very bad thing to do - it can  change the meaning of code in those headers!